# Java(Android) stuck in while loop

Tags: java, android, loops, while-loop

when I run my app it will continuously be stuck in a while loop. It should leave the while loop when a button is pressed, however even after pressing a button it continues to loop.

```
View.OnClickListener listener11 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            temp1 = button[0];
            temp3 = button[0].getBackground();
            state++;
        }
    };


        while(state == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            button[0].setOnClickListener(listener11);
        }
```

variable:
state is an **int**      temp1 is a **button**        temp3 is a **Drawable**

the delay is there because I actually have 20 buttons and I have the setOnClickListeners for all the buttons inside that while loop so I think it causes it to crash without the delay. Another question would be is it possible to have the setOnClickListeners outside the while loop but still be able to check for button clicks inside the loop?

Comment: Are you positive the onClick listener is being invoked?  Have you tried adding a print statement to see the value of state being incremented?

Comment: Is this happening on the main thread?

Comment: Its usually a bad idea to sleep the main thread since it will stop the all user interaction from processing

Comment: Once you have set the listener it makes no sense to sleep the main thread... the listener will remain set either way.

Comment: I don't think calling setOnClickListeners for 20 buttons in a row will cause a crash. What is the crash you are getting?

Comment: View.OnClickListener listener11 doesn't appear to be going off because I just added a text box and wrote the line "text.setText("one");" in the listener11 and the text box doesn't change to "one".

Comment: The crash I would get with 20 setOnClickListeners would just be "app has stopped responding" and asks me if I want to wait or close it.

Comment: The reason I used the thread sleep was because I didn't completely understand how to use the handler method in a while loop, I just wanted to use a small delay :(

Comment: It seems your app is getting stuck in an infinite loop, adding a delay didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are pressing the button while the thread is in a sleeping state causing the event to not be triggered and therefor the state to never change.

Comment: Once the while loops starts I will constantly keep pressing the button. Even if the sleeping state wasn't there, I'd still be stuck in the loop.

Comment: It makes no sense to set a listener in a while loop, it should only ever be done once

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the code is supposed to be doing because I have no idea of the context, but I think think you could remove the `while` loop altogether:

```
// initialize the listener
View.OnClickListener listener11 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // add code that runs when button is clicked here
    }
};

// now that we have the listener all set up we add it to the button, at which point it just keeps listening for you, no need to put the thread to sleep
button[0].setOnClickListener(listener11);
```

**UPDATE:**
So because you want to see if the second value matches the first value you could use a helper method:

```
private String firstValue = "";
public boolean isMatch(String mostRecentValue) {
    boolean match = false;
    if (firstValue.isEmpty()) {
        firstValue = mostRecentValue;
    } else {
        match = firstValue.equals(mostRecentValue);
        firstValue = "";
    }
    return match;
}
```

This method takes a value and if it is the first click the value is saved, if it is the second click it compares it with the first click and then resets the method. A `boolean` is returned `false` for no match, and `true` for a match. Call this method from within the `onClick()` method and pass in the buttons value. I've used `String` as an example value but you could use any object type.

Comment: The reason for the while loop (I have 2) is because I want to store a button's property(the one that I press out of the 20 buttons that I have) into a temp button(temp1) and compare that temp button with another temp button (temp2). But I wanted the first button I pressed to be stored in temp1 and the second button I pressed to be stored in temp2.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the while loop and just set all the listeners in a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i< button.length; i++) {
    button[0].setTag(i);
    button[0].setOnClickListener(listener11);
}
```

And then change your listener to be something like:

```
private boolean firstClick = true;
View.OnClickListener listener11 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(firstClick) {
            firstClick = false;
            temp1 = button[(int)view.getTag()];
        } else {
            temp2 = button[(int)view.getTag()];
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be misunderstanding what setOnClickListener is doing.  It's not handling the click, it is setting up the click handler.  The line `button[0].setOnClickListener(listener11);` would be part of your activity initialisation and then not called again.

The reason you get stuck is because the main thread is busy in the while loop and isn't given an opportunity to process click events.  Click events are handled on the main thread but only when it's not already busy doing something.  In this case, it's forever busy in the while loop.  For example, if the main thread was processing a method that would take 10 seconds to complete and you tap on a button 3 seconds into it, the button press wouldn't be handled for another 7 seconds.  At which point, the previously set listener11 would be executed.

What you seem to be trying to achieve is already handled by the [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html).  You need to be thinking in terms of event handling. So in other words, all your logic needs to go in listener11 or something similar.